# Finding subdirectories in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to search through all the subdirectories in the current directory for a directory named 'jdk1.7'. I have written a statement like

`find -type d -name 'jdk1*'`

But I am not getting any results. I have verified that the directory is present in the directory hierarchy of the current directory.

Comment: What does `ls -ld subdir1/subdir2/.../jdk1.7` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are two possibilities:

- `jdk1.7` isn't an actual directory.
- `jdk1.7` is a directory, but not an actual subdirectory of `.`.

Consider the following example:

```
$ mkdir a a/jdk
$ touch a/jdk/somefile
$ mkdir b c
$ ln -s ../a/jdk b/
$ ln -s ../a c/
$ find -L | sort
.
./a
./a/jdk
./a/jdk/somefile
./b
./b/jdk
./b/jdk/somefile
./c
./c/a
./c/a/jdk
./c/a/jdk/somefile
$ find a -type d -name jdk
a/jdk
$ find b -type d -name jdk
$ find c -type d -name jdk
```

For most practical purposes, `jdk` can be thought of as a subdirectory of `a`, `b` and `c`. However, the `find` command will succeed only for the first.

`./b/jdk` is a symbolic link to `a/jdk`, so it will not match the `-type d` predicate. It would match `-type l`, but so will symbolic links to files.

`./c/a/jdk` is an actual directory, but `./c/a` is just a symbolic link to `./a`. By default, find doesn't follow symbolic links, so it won't examine the apparent contents of `./c/a`.

To instruct find to follow symbolic links whenever they are encountered, use the `-L` flag:

```
$ find -L a b c -type d -name jdk
a/jdk
b/jdk
c/a/jdk
```

Comment: The problem was indeed of symlinks. The directory that I was looking for wasn't actually a directory. It was a symbolic link. Using -L option with find actually solved the problem.